# Support of the fundamental class of irreducible components of partial Springer fibres corresponding to flag signatures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, rt.representation-theory

The (partial) Springer resolution is defined as a map $\mu: T^*\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{N}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the partial flag variety consisting of $n$-step partial flags of $\mathbb{C}^d$, and $\mathcal{N}$ a set of nilpotent operators $\mathcal{N} = \{X \in \text{End}(\mathbb{C}^d) : X^n = 0\}$. A *partial* Springer fibre is the set $\mathcal{F}^X := \mu^{-1}(X) = \{F_\bullet : X F_i \subset F_{i-1}\}$.

Ginzburg has a construction of certain irreps of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ on the (top Borel-Moore homology) of these fibres $H(\mathcal{F}^X)$ (the vector space spanned by the fundamental classes of the irreducible components of $\mathcal{F}^X$). In particular, they are irreducible, with highest weight given by the Jordan type of $X$ (a partition consisting of the sizes of the Jordan blocks in its decomposition), see Chriss-Ginzburg Theorem 4.2.3 for example.

In the proof of this theorem, the first part goes (below is an abridged version):

> For any partition (or sequence/composition) $\lambda$ the fundamental class of the diagonal $T_\Delta^*(\mathcal{F}_\lambda \times \mathcal{F}_\lambda)$ acts as the identity map on any cycle in $H(\mathcal{F}^X)$ supported only on $\mathcal{F}_\lambda$, annihilating any other cycle.

I am looking *hopefully* for a reference to why this statement should be true. I can think of an equivalent statement that is (at least) easier for me to understand:

> Let $F$ be an irreducible component of the partial Springer fibre $\mathcal{F}^X$, and let $[F]$ be its fundamental class in the top Borel-Moore homology. Then the support of $F$ is contained in $\mathcal{F}_\mu$ *if and only if* $F \subseteq \mathcal{F}_\mu$.

A point to make here is that the general definition (that I'm comfortable with) of the *support* of a cycle (as a sum of singular simplices) is the union of the images of each of the simplices.
In the case of the Borel-Moore homology, it seems that the *support* of a cycle (as a linear combination of fundamental classes - the distinguished basis) is the union of the irreducible components whose fundamental classes appear with nonzero coefficient in the expression of that cycle in the vector space $H(\mathcal{F}^X)$.

I am unable to see how to reconcile these two definitions, but surely they must be equivalent in the BM homology.
In lieu of a reference to the previous statement/s or even the proof in Ginzburg's book, a hint on why they may or may not be true (even just morally), or even better a reference/outline, would be desired in the answer.

Finally, this is a repost of the question I asked on MSE found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772206/support-of-the-fundamental-class-of-irreducible-components-of-partial-springer-f).
This is also my first time posting on MO, by advice of my supervisor - please let me know if there are any improvements I can make to the question.